# Difference between 'using' and '#using' directive?

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, using-directives

According to MSDN is:

> The using directive has two uses:
>
> 1)To allow the use of types in a
>   namespace so that you do not have to
>   qualify the use of a   type in that
>   namespace:

```
 using System.Text;
```

> 2)To create an alias for a namespace
>   or a type. This is called a using
>   alias directive.

```
 using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
```

**Edit1:**
When we say `#using<mscorlib.dll>` what does it do?

Is `#using` directive specific to C++/CLI ?

What is the basic difference between `using` and `#using`?

Comment: There's no `#using` in your code.

Comment: @Kobi -- I didn't post any code as yet.It's just information from MSDN.Check 'Edit1', I have made a few changes to be more clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #using directive is C++. Basically it

> Imports metadata into a program
>   compiled with /clr.

It is is used to import Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) file for its managed data and managed constructs.

mscorlib.dll is automatically referenced when compiling with /clr.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab9swk4(v=VS.100).aspx

`using` on the other hand is applicable to both C++ and C# and you have defined its uses already. In C++:

```
using namespace System::Reflection;
```

Also:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello ";
   using namespace std;
   cout << "World." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Neither `using` nor `#using` is meaningful in C.

Answer (score 0):

`#using` is only used in C++ and includes another file to the one it's contained in.

`using` is specific to C# and allows you to use classes from the namespace it specifies.

Comment: Not true. `using` is a C++ keyword!

Comment: Right!  It's used to use the components of a namespace, just like in C#.  I rarely use the using keyword in C++, my bad!